# Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fail

Tags: sql

Everytime i try to create the survey table i keep getting this error Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails.

Table - users

```
users (
username VARCHAR(16), 
password VARCHAR(16), 
email VARCHAR(64),
first_name VARCHAR(32),
surname VARCHAR(64),
telephone VARCHAR(16),
dob DATE,user_type 
VARCHAR(6),
PRIMARY KEY(username)),
```

Table - survey

```
CREATE TABLE survey 
(id  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
title VARCHAR(64), 
type VARCHAR(40),
PRIMARY KEY(id)
FOREIGN KEY(username)
REFERENCES users(username)),
```

Comment: Does the users table already contain data? Are you inserting any rows into the survey table after creating it?

Comment: Not sure about your query. Because creating table wouldnt give such error. It might be you are deleting the table with foreign key.